# understanding of emacs align-regexp

Tags: regex, emacs, alignment, text-alignment

I've read the emacs documentation for `align-regexp` but still have difficulty in understanding how it works. What I'm talking about is its prefixed form <kbd>C-u M-x align-regexp</kbd>, not the simple form <kbd>M-x align-regexp</kbd>. My question is:

- Does the first parameter (the regex) have to match the whole line of string? What if the regex only matchs a part of the string?
- What to supply to the second parameter (Parenthesis group to modify (justify if negative))? As I understand here I need to supply a captured group number (count from 1), right? Does "justify if negative" means, if I want group 3 to right aligned, I'll supply `-3` as the input?
- What does the third parameter "amount of spacing (or column if negative)" mean? I just totally don't understand what this parameter does.

I've collect some text examples to practice. If anyone can use below text as examples that will be very helpful.

**From**

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students, :comment => "学生信息表" do |t|
      t.string :political_status, :comment => "政治面貌"
      t.string :education_level, :comment => "培养层次"
      t.string :enroll_method, :comment => "入学方式"
      t.date :enrolled_at, :comment => "入学时间"
      t.string :charge_type, :comment => "收费类别"
      t.string :enrolled_year, :comment => "学籍年度"
      t.string :enrolled_place, :comment => "生源所在地"
      t.string :bank_card_number, :comment => "银行卡号"
      t.string :bank_account_number,  :comment => "银行账号"
      t.boolean :is_active_duty, :default => false, :comment => "是否现役军人"
      t.boolean :is_equivalent_degree, :default => false, :comment => "是否同等学历"
      t.boolean :is_on_record, :default => true, :comment => "是否在籍"
      t.boolean :is_at_school, :default => true, :comment => "是否在校"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**To**

```
class CreateStudents < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :students, :comment => "学生信息表" do |t|
      t.string  :political_status,     :comment => "政治面貌"
      t.string  :education_level,      :comment => "培养层次"
      t.string  :enroll_method,        :comment => "入学方式"
      t.date    :enrolled_at,          :comment => "入学时间"
      t.string  :charge_type,          :comment => "收费类别"
      t.string  :enrolled_year,        :comment => "学籍年度"
      t.string  :enrolled_place,       :comment => "生源所在地"
      t.string  :bank_card_number,     :comment => "银行卡号"
      t.string  :bank_account_number,  :comment => "银行账号"
      t.boolean :is_active_duty,       :default => false,  :comment => "是否现役军人"
      t.boolean :is_equivalent_degree, :default => false,  :comment => "是否同等学历"
      t.boolean :is_on_record,         :default => true,   :comment => "是否在籍"
      t.boolean :is_at_school,         :default => true,   :comment => "是否在校"
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**From**

```
my @primes = (
    1,2,3,5,7,
    11,13,17,19,23,
    29,31,37,41,43,
);
```

**To**

```
my @primes = (
    1,  2,  3,  5,  7,
    11, 13, 17, 19, 23,
    29, 31, 37, 41, 43,
);
```

Comment: Duplicate of https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/2644/understanding-of-emacs-align-regexp

Answer (score 0):

For the first case, select the region (below the `create table`) and try <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp` `\(:\)` `-1` `1` `y`.

For the second case, select the region and try <kbd>C-u</kbd><kbd>M-x</kbd>`align-regexp` `\([0-9]+\)` `-1` `1` `y`.

As you can see, the regex doesn't have to match the whole string. Your understanding of the second parameter seems correct. For more details, read the help for `align-rules-list`:

```
`column'    For alignment rules, if the `column' attribute is set --
        which must be an integer, or a symbol whose value is an
        integer -- it will be used as the column in which to align
        the alignment character.  If the text on a particular line
        happens to overrun that column, a single space character,
        or tab stop (see `align-to-tab-stop') will be added
        between the last text character and the alignment
        character.

`spacing'   Alignment rules may also override the amount of spacing
        that would normally be used by providing a `spacing'
        attribute.  This must be an integer, or a list of integers
        corresponding to the number of parenthesis groups matched
        by the `group' attribute.  If a list of value is used, and
        any of those values is nil, `align-default-spacing' will
        be used for that subgroup.  See `align-default-spacing'
        for more details on spacing, tab stops, and how to
        indicate how much spacing should be used.  If TAB-STOP is
        present, it will override the value of `align-to-tab-stop'
        for that rule.
```

Comment: You're missing a backslash on `\(:)`. Also, this doesn't really answer the question.